# React native iOS error - "RCTNetworking.sendRequest not found"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting a compilation error `RCTNetworking.sendRequest not found` in react native iOS after creating and importing a new react component. ESlint isn't showing any JS errors introduced from the change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this error can be caused by having multiple debugger tabs open in Chrome.

As a previous answer said, doing a Clean and a Reset Content will temporarily clear the error, but if you have multiple debugger tabs open, as soon as you try debugging again the error will come right back.

Try closing all of the debugger tabs and then reopening only one. This should fix it.

Answer (score 6):

The error went away after running `Product -> Clean` in Xcode and `Reset Content and Settings` in Simulator. This didn't seem to be an issue with my code, so it might be a bug in react native.

Comment: Is this the issue you've experienced: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5607?  In my case resetting debugger / cleaning did help but as soon as Chrome debugger was turned on, it reappeared.

Comment: yura: yeah, that's the one I was seeing. I didn't see the same behavior around chrome debugger though - hopefully there are more leads for you in that issue thread.

Comment: @yura see my answer about multiple debugger tabs being open.

Comment: @Clayton Gulick - Thank you for following up!